# Adding and Removing Interceptors

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have a scenario where I add an interceptor containing an `Authorization` `String` in the header to get back a `token` from the API. When I get back a token, I wish to add a new interceptor which will add the received token to the header of all subsequent requests.

How do I remove the previous Interceptor which contains the `Authorization` token since it's no longer needed?

```
private void removeAuthorizationInterceptor()
{
    for (Interceptor interceptor : App.getOkHttpClient().newBuilder().networkInterceptors())
    {
        // Find the interceptor which has the Authorization token and remove it
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in my context I have three different APIs and only one need to use interceptor (AddHeaderAndCookie)  which add api signature and cookie required for this API, other APIS don't need this, how can i achieve this

Answer (score 4):

You just need to create a new OkHttpClient.Builder and then mutate the list. I think the difference from your code is that you need to use the new client you just built for the next request.

```
OkHttpClient client = ...;

OkHttpClient.Builder b = client.newBuilder();
b.networkInterceptors().removeIf(MyInterceptor.class::isInstance);
client2 = b.build();
```

This is Java 8 code, but you can change the removeIf for Java 7, e.g. iterate through and add everything except your interceptor to a new list.